# primary key is always indexed in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, primary-key, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

> You can create a clustered index on a column other than primary key column if a nonclustered primary key constraint was specified.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342.aspx

So the above told me: I can create a clustered index on columns other than primary key.

I think it also conveys that a primary key should either be a nonclustered primary key or clustered key. Is it possible a primary key is not indexed?

What's more:

> When you create a UNIQUE constraint, a unique nonclustered index is created to enforce a UNIQUE constraint by default. You can specify a unique clustered index if a clustered index on the table does not already exist.

Does this mean a unique constraint has to create a clustered index or a nonclustered index?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it possible a primary key is not indexed?

No, it's not.

Some kind of an index is required to police the `PRIMARY KEY`, otherwise it would require scanning the whole table on each insert (to ensure uniqueness).

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181043%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> The Database Engine automatically creates a unique index to enforce the uniqueness requirement of the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint. If a clustered index does not already exist on the table or a nonclustered index is not explicitly specified, a unique, clustered index is created to enforce the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

---

> Does this mean a unique constraint has to create a clustered index or a nonclustered index?

Yes, for the same reasons.

---

`PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` are logical concepts, while the index just has a side effect of implementing them efficiently. So, strictly speaking, `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE` and `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` mean different things.

If, in the future, some bright head invents a way to use Pauli principle or quantum entanglement or whatever to enforce uniqueness on physical level, `SQL Server 2155` may employ it to enforce the constraint, but it will still have to create the B-Tree for the index.

Comment: I think the answer might be misleading based on the question title.  The answer is YES a pk is always indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No,

Every table in SQL Server should have only one clustered index. Others indexes (non-clustered) use from clustered index. Primary key is clustered index commonly. But primary-key is always indexed unlike foreign key.

```
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/972f0/1
```

Comment: *every table ... should have only one clustered index* - every table can **NEVER** ever have more than one clustered index! It's not a *should not* restriction - it's a fixed **CANNOT** restriction. There is no way to have more than one clustered index.