# Performance by using UPDATE / UPDATE TOP (1)

Tags: sql-server

I'm normally using:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1='test' WHERE ID=10
```

But will it be more efficiently to use the following statement:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) table1 SET field1='test' WHERE ID=10
```

if I have a lots of records?

The ID Column is a primary key and autoincremented too.

Comment: Using `TOP` in `UPDATE` is a deprecated feature. Don't worry about performance (there will be none in any case if `ID` is indexed, which it is in your case), just don't use it.

Comment: If the column is a primary key, SQL Server 'knows' there's only zero or one matching key and will not cause a table scan. You should be able to see this in the query plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ID` column is a Primary Key, then there will be at most a single record affected by your `UPDATE` query.

If your Primary Key is by default a Clustered Index, then the performance should be similar in both cases.

Even if when creating your PK, you specify it as non-clustered, then you still get a performance boost when searching / selecting / identifying / filtering records (because you're using `WHERE`). This might not be as fast as the clustered index PK, but the performance difference should be negligible.

When creating a PK, you're forced to pick one of the two indexing types for your key, as [mentioned and explained here in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658536/1266737).

Hence, both versions of the `UPDATE` query should have similar performance (possibly small differences when running on different occasions due to other ancillary operations).

**In conclusion:**

If you have a Primary Key on your ID column, and you're using it in the `FILTERING` part of the query (`WHERE`), then you should be fine when you're querying thousands, millions and possibly even up to billions of records.

**Disclaimer:**

The performance / speed of the `UPDATE` query also depends on what other indexes need to be updated, due to the changing values (indexes which contain the `field1` as their key), triggers on your table, cascading rules for foreign keys etc.